# NumberFormatException при передачи значение из selected

Tags: java, jsp, servlet

В сервлете, на месте " `MusicType musicType = musicTypeDAO.read(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("musicTypes")));"`
NumberFormatException эксепшен, но я хз почему
Вид:

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<%@ page import="java.util.*"%>
<%@page import="Model.MusicType"%>
<%@ page import="DAO.MusicTypeDAO"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <%
        MusicTypeDAO dao = new MusicTypeDAO();
        List<MusicType> musicTypes = dao.getAll();
    %>
    <h1 align="center">Registration</h1>
    <p align="center">${errorsRegistr}</p>

    <table align="center">
        <form action="RegistrServlet" name="RegistrServlet" method="GET">
        <tr>
            <td>Login:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="login" size="10"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Password:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="password" size="10"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Confirm password:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="confirmPassword" size="10"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>First name:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="firstName" size="10"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Last name:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="lastName" size="10"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Age:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="age" size="10"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Counry:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="country" size="10"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Street:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="street" size="10"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Zip code:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="login" size="10"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Music type:</td>
            <td><select name="musicTypes">
                    <%
                        for (MusicType music : musicTypes) {
                    %>
                    <option value="<%=music.getId()%>"><%=music.getTypeName()%></option>
                    <%
                        }
                    %>
            </select></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="submit" value="Создать"></input>
            </form></td>
            <td><a href="index.jsp"><input type="submit"
                    value="Вернуться на главную"></a></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Сервлет

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        RoleDAO roleDAO = new RoleDAO();
        MusicTypeDAO musicTypeDAO = new MusicTypeDAO();
        UserDAO userDAO = new UserDAO();

        String login = request.getParameter("login");
        String password = request.getParameter("password");
        String firstName = request.getParameter("firstName");
        String lastName = request.getParameter("lastName");
        String ageStr = request.getParameter("age");

        String country = request.getParameter("country");
        String street = request.getParameter("street");
        String zipStr = request.getParameter("zip");

        MusicType musicType = musicTypeDAO.read(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("musicTypes")));//вот тут нул поинтер
        Address address = new Address(1, country, street, Integer.parseInt(zipStr));

        Role role = new Role(3, "User");
        HashSet<MusicType> musicTypes = new HashSet<MusicType>();
        musicTypes.add(musicType);
        User user = new User(1, login, password, firstName, lastName, Integer.parseInt(ageStr), address, role,
                musicTypes);
        userDAO.create(user);
        HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
        session.setAttribute("id", user.getId());
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/UserServlet").forward(request, response);
    }
```

Стек ошибок:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [RegistrServlet] in context with path [/MusicStore] threw exception
java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:542)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
    at Servlets.RegistrServlet.doGet(RegistrServlet.java:45)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:522)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:1110)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:785)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1425)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

фев 21, 2017 8:38:05 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext reload
INFO: Reloading Context with name [/MusicStore] has started
фев 21, 2017 8:38:05 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase clearReferencesJdbc
WARNING: The web application [MusicStore] registered the JDBC driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
фев 21, 2017 8:38:05 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase clearReferencesThreads
WARNING: The web application [MusicStore] appears to have started a thread named [MySQL Statement Cancellation Timer] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
 java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
 java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:526)
 java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
фев 21, 2017 8:38:08 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
фев 21, 2017 8:38:08 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext reload
INFO: Reloading Context with name [/MusicStore] is completed
```

Comment: попробуйте там использовать String.valueOf(ваше значение), обычно оно появляется при попытке распарсить строку как число

Comment: вот http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18711896 посмотрите еще

Comment: я вижу как бы `NumberFormatException` а не `NullPointerException`...

Answer (score 1):

В stacktrace ошибка не `NullPointerException` а `NumberFormatException`.

Возникает потому что `request.getParameter("musicTypes")` возвращает `null`, а не строку

Comment: Я это понял, но почему так происходит?

Comment: можеш потому что вы это поле не передаете с jsp ? или его нет в форме?

Comment: как я вижу все другие поля - это `input`-ы, а `musicTypes` - нет, значит проблема в здесь